FindInstance is not able to find a solution that can be found easily by random substitution
Why is FindInstance not able to find any instance when random substitution finds them very quickly.
cond = (-((-1 + p4) q4) + p4 q4)/Sqrt[(1 - p4)^2 + q4^2] > 0 && 
   q1/Sqrt[p1^2 + q1^2] > 0 && ((1 - p2) q1 + (-1 + p1) q2)/
    Sqrt[(-1 + p2)^2 + q2^2] > 
    0 && ((p1 - p3) (-q1 + q2) + (-p1 + p2) (-q1 + q3))/
    Sqrt[(-p1 + p3)^2 + (-q1 + q3)^2] > 
    0 && ((p2 - p4) (-q2 + q3) + (-p2 + p3) (-q2 + q4))/
    Sqrt[(-p2 + p4)^2 + (-q2 + q4)^2] > 
    0 && (-((-p3 + p4) q3) + p3 (-q3 + q4))/Sqrt[p3^2 + q3^2] > 0;

Cases[Table[{{p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4}, cond} /. 
   Thread[{p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4} -> 
     RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 8]], 100], {_, True}]

FindInstance[cond, {p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4}, Reals]


{{{6.68036, 3.91567, -7.43214, -4.80942, -3.02466, -9.21947, 2.54473, 
   2.59449}, 
  True}, {{6.6578, 9.78615, -0.662982, -2.56718, 4.77922, -2.29812, 
   9.60466, 9.65135}, 
  True}, {{-0.189909, 3.6298, -8.40467, 9.85626, 0.03939, -3.50218, 
   8.09842, 7.80604}, True}}

(* FindInstance keeps running forever without output*)


Perhaps not surprisingly, RandomPoint has the same problem.

It seems that by numericizing the problem, you can somehow make FindInstance not get stuck ...
FindInstance[N@cond, {p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4}, Reals]
(* {{p1 -> -(252/5), q1 -> 9/2, p2 -> 181/2, q2 -> -(56/5), p3 -> 377/5, 
     q3 -> 592/5, p4 -> -46, q4 -> 344/5}} *)


I thought FindInstance never tries to solve expressions symbolically.

@azerbajdzan, FindInstance is one of those "magical" functions that does all sort of weird things and heuristics ... I guess that it gets stuck somewhere when trying to "deal" with the symbolic expression, but I don't really have the exact explanation of what is really going on :)

Interesting: FindInstance[N@cond, {p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4}, Reals,   RandomSeeding -> k] runs forever for k = 4, 11, 14, 33, 34,... OTOH, on your original case, without N@..., random seeding hasn't produced any successes for me.

The solver FindInstance calls on N@cond works on cond, but in the case of cond, FindInstance doesn't get to it (System`InstanceDump`redinst[..., 5, 2, False].

@MichaelE2, interesting ... So changing RandomSeeding seems to be another trick to try making FindInstance work when it doesn't.

@Domen Yep. I thought its main purpose was to give different values.

The system cond consists of 6 inequalities in 8 variables.  Let us  solve these inequalities separately. Then
FindInstance[Table[Reduce[cond[[j]], Reals], {j, 1, Dimensions[cond][[1]]}], {p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4}, Reals, 4]


{{p1 -> 0, q1 -> 168, p2 -> 2/3, q2 -> 0, p3 -> 15/76, q3 -> 168,  p4 -> -83, q4 -> 58}, {p1 -> 91/402, q1 -> 51, p2 -> 121/131,  q2 -> 0, p3 -> 121/131, q3 -> 51, p4 -> 3/5, q4 -> 61}, {p1 -> 1,  q1 -> 32, p2 -> 5/6, q2 -> 0, p3 -> 87, q3 -> 32, p4 -> 132,  q4 -> 73}, {p1 -> 1, q1 -> 82, p2 -> -53, q2 -> 0, p3 -> 24,  q3 -> 82, p4 -> -83, q4 -> 74}}

succeeds.

It should be noticed that FindInstance[  Reduce[cond, Reals], {p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4}, Reals, 4] fails.

Actually, the system cond consists of 6 inequalities in 8 variables.  Your solution still works with this correction.  I believe that this solution works, because Reduce in this instance eliminates Sqrt.

@bbgodfrey: Many thanks from me to you for your valuable comment. Fixed. You are right concerning Sqrts.

Remove branch cut difficulties and it is faster:
FindInstance[
  Simplify[cond, 
   Thread[Cases[cond, HoldPattern[_^2 + _^2], Infinity] > 0]], {p1, 
   q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4}, Reals] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.021153, {{p1 -> 0, q1 -> 1, p2 -> 3/2, q2 -> -2, p3 -> 3/2, 
   q3 -> -1, p4 -> 0, q4 -> 1}}}
*)

